# SQL Server Where Clause Path for XML Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Main problem is how to use a `where` clause in SQL for XML.

I need to return the row of XML where the  "team" appears in.

You can view my example fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/de221e/2

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id int,
  value xml
  )

  INSERT INTO test (id, value)
  VALUES 
  ('1', N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?> <Atts>
        <Att>
            <Name>test</Name>
        </Att>
                <Att>
            <Name>team</Name>
        </Att>
                <Att>
            <Name>test</Name>
        </Att>
        </Atts>'),
          ('2', N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?> <Atts>
        <Att>
            <Name>test</Name>
        </Att>
                <Att>
            <Name>test</Name>
        </Att>
                <Att>
            <Name>test</Name>
        </Att>
        </Atts>');
```

query:

```
select * from test
where value.value('(/Atts/Att/Name)[1]','varchar(max)') = 'team'
```

This doesn't return anything.

However if you do where clause on first name that appears in the XML it works e.g.

```
select * from test
where value.value('(/Atts/Att/Name)[1]','varchar(max)') = 'test'
```

returns:

```
| id |                                                                                             value |
|----|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1 | <Atts><Att><Name>test</Name></Att><Att><Name>team</Name></Att><Att><Name>test</Name></Att></Atts> |
|  2 | <Atts><Att><Name>test</Name></Att><Att><Name>test</Name></Att><Att><Name>test</Name></Att></Atts> |
```

Expected results is this query should return:

```
select * from test
where value.value('(/Atts/Att/Name)[1]','varchar(max)') = 'team'

| id |                                                                                             value |
|----|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1 | <Atts><Att><Name>test</Name></Att><Att><Name>team</Name></Att><Att><Name>test</Name></Att></Atts> |
```

Any ideas how I can return "team" if it appears in XML but isn't in the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `exist()` method. It will check for the 'team' value regardless of its position. [exist() Method (xml Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/exist-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)

> SQL

```
select * from test
where value.exist('/Atts/Att/Name[./text()="team"]') = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the second one.  You are looking at the first one.

This gives you the results you want

```
select * from test
where value.value('(/Atts/Att/Name)[2]','varchar(max)') = 'team'
```